# Melhoria em meu código (básico) para importar arquivos no excell VBA

Tags: vba

Boa noite.

Aos experts em vba, venho trabalhando em várias planilhas com essa lógica de código, para importar arquivos, e após isso, trabalhar nos números delas seja com macro ou fórmulas.

Gostaria de receber dicas de aprimoramento deste código, redução de linhas, seja o que for. Qualquer dica é bem-vinda!

Obrigado.

```
Sub AtualizarRelatorioGeral()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    SaveChanges = False

    Dim Arquivo(18) As String

    Arquivo(1) = "zpp03ontem"
    Arquivo(2) = "vl10a"
    Arquivo(3) = "mb51consumomensal"
    Arquivo(4) = "mb51repassegerado"
    Arquivo(5) = "mb52peixerev"
    Arquivo(6) = "mb52peixepro"
    Arquivo(7) = "mb52exp"
    Arquivo(8) = "mb52repassesaldo"
    Arquivo(9) = "zsd17"
    Arquivo(10) = "zsd25fat"
    Arquivo(11) = "zsd25dev"
    Arquivo(12) = "mc.9estoquecd"
    Arquivo(13) = "mc.9consumo"
    Arquivo(14) = "mc.9centro"
    Arquivo(15) = "mc.9cdhipet"
    Arquivo(16) = "mc.9valor"
    Arquivo(17) = "zpp25"
    Arquivo(18) = "mc.9produto"

    For i = 1 To 18
        Sheets(Arquivo(i)).Visible = True
    Next i

    Set WBgeral = ActiveWorkbook

    'IMPORTAR ARQUIVOS
    For i = 1 To 18
        WBgeral.Activate
        Sheets(Arquivo(i)).Activate
        Cells.Select
        Selection.Clear
        Workbooks.OpenXML ("C:\macrosm\prerelatoriolucimara\" & Arquivo(i) & ".xls")
        Range("A1").Select
        Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        WBgeral.Activate
        Sheets(Arquivo(i)).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Workbooks(Arquivo(i)).Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next i
    'IMPORTAR ARQUIVOS

    Sheets("Principal").Activate

    For i = 1 To 18
        'Sheets(Arquivo(i)).Visible = False
    Next i

    Cells(4, 16).Value = Date
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    SaveChanges = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Você está realizando muitas interações entre o VBA e a planilha Excel e isto é lento. Por exemplo, [evite a utilização de .Select/ Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Você também está abrindo vários arquivos, portanto isto é lento mesmo... Há um site do SE para estes tipos de perguntas: o [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Legal o codereview, não sabia... mas aproveitando a pergunta acho que se separasse cada parte do seu código em diferentes funções cada uma fazendo sua parte (Dividir e Conquistar) e ao invés de ter no código o nome dos arquivos, poderia ter uma pasta específica (se possível), para ler tudo o que tem nessa pasta, por exemplo pasta **carregar**, **carregados**, tudo que for lido corretamente vai para pasta "carregados". Mas só uma ideia mesmo.

Comment: Cross-post: [Importing files into Excel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/200006/importing-files-into-excel)